# How to pass store explicitly into as a prop to "Connect()"

Tags: reactjs, phantomjs, redux, react-redux

I am trying to test my React component and getting the following error.

> Invariant Violation: Could not find "store" in either the context or props of "Connect()". Either wrap the root component in a <Provider>, or explicitly pass "store" as a prop to "Connect()".

The error comes while rendering the Component in the test.

```
beforeEach(() => {
  Component = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(<SideMenu />);
});
```

It works fine when rendering the Component on the page. However in test, I am not able to pass the store explicitly into the Component.

Can someone point in the right direction?

Comment: `<SideMenu store={store} />` is how you explicitly do it but there's something else missing in this picture. What is Connect and can you paste your entire component and test, please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`connect` is a decorator provided by `react-redux`. A component `connect`ed to redux is a smart component and expects store to be available either through a `prop` or as the error message says via a `Provider`.

While testing a smart component, you can supply mocked store as a `prop`. However, when there is another child component down the line, who expects the `store`, the `prop` way won't work.

Here's a way to supply the `store` to a component that `import`s a child component which subscribes to the `store`.

```
const initialState = {key: 'value'};
const store = createStore(initialState);

component = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(
  <Provider store={store(initialState)}>
    {() => <SideMenu />}
  </Provider>
);
```

Comment: But how do you pass it to Connect instead, like the OP asks?

Comment: what is createStore?

Comment: createStore is probably the function exposed by the redux npm lib

Comment: @jorisw See this comment by Dan Abramov: https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/issues/390#issuecomment-221389608

Answer (score 6):

To answer the question (I ran into this and the accepted answer is not what I needed), create a new method like:

```
function connectWithStore(store, WrappedComponent, ...args) {
  let ConnectedWrappedComponent = connect(...args)(WrappedComponent)
  return function (props) {
    return <ConnectedWrappedComponent {...props} store={store} />
  }
}
```

Then, for connect, use:

```
const ConnectedApp = connectWithStore(store, App, mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps,)

export default ConnectedApp;
```

See here: https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/issues/390#issuecomment-221389608

Answer (score 2):

In most cases, I found that importing component itself in tests works fine for me.

SideMenu.js:

```
export class SideMenu extends React.Component {
 // implementation
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps,)(SideMenu)
```

SideMenu.spec.js:

```
import { SideMenu } from 'path/to/SideMenu.js'

const props = {
  // provide all necessary stubs and mocks for redux props and actions 
}
component = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(<SideMenu {...props} />);
```

Note: as Салман pointed out this approach won't work when there is another child component down the line, who expects the `store`.